# Visual Studio, Plugins, and Nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, visual-studio-2012, continuous-integration, nuget

Normally "[continuous package integration](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/07/18/continuous-package-integration-nuget-vs-source-control)" involves source control, a build server, and participating teams fetching updated packages as often as they like.  But I'm looking for a more extreme version of this story - without CM - that happens entirely on a developer's machine, all in one swoop.  A more detailed description of what I want goes like this...

Using Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, assume a "foo.csproj" application that implements a plugin system.  Each plugin represents a nuget package and has a corresponding Visual Studio project.  Each of these projects is part of the same VS solution that contains the base application.

I want the following development story:

1. Change source code for a plugin.
2. Build solution, or perform a debug-launch, which causes msbuild to...

   1. rebuild the changed plugin(s)
   2. nuget then packages and uploads each plugin to a local repository (which can be just a subfolder of the VS solution)
   3. rebuild the base application.
   4. refresh the base application's nuget-plugin dependencies, which were just updated in prior steps.  *Notes*:

      1. This assumes MSBuild magically knows not to perform this last step until all plugins are built, packaged, and uploaded.
      2. The "foo" application could itself use nuget.core to refresh the packages, but in this case I'm assuming that the VS build process did this step.

I would like to know if this story is common enough that there are "common" (msbuild?) scripts for this.

My own guess of how this should be handled is as follows:

1. All plugin projects are placed in a common "Plugins" folder somewhere in the VS solution folder structure.
2. The base application "project dependencies" are configured with references to all the plugin projects.
   *Note:* I don't like the idea of managing these project dependencies manually.
3. The base application "foo.csproj" has a build step that scans the "foo.csproj" XML for dependencies it has in the "plugins" folder, and initiates the nuget packaging and deployment for each.
4. The base application then initiates the nuget "update all". Hopefully this is possible even though msbuild already mid-stride in execution.

In short, the base application is able to instantly consume plugins that have been altered.  This is done without check-ins, a build-server, or manual and arbitrary requests to update plugin packages.

If pre-existing scripts do not already exist for this story, then I'll make my own.  But I'd still like to know:

1. Can step 2, immediately above, be converted to something generic?  That is, how can I convince msbuild not to build the "base application" until all projects in a particular folder have already been built?  Remember, I'd like not to manage the project dependencies manually.
2. Is there anything flawed with this overall approach?

I would be particularly interested to know if there is an already existing nuget-visual-studio integration that assists with this story that I may have overlooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite a long question to answer, so not sure I'm covering everything in this one; I'll do my best. First, your scenario is not uncommon. The first 2 steps of your planned approach seem OK to me (you're free to choose the location of the plug-in projects).

One thing's for sure: you'll have to manually define the build order, because your solution has no idea of knowing whether the projects consuming (NuGet) plug-ins have a dependency to the projects containing the source code for those plug-ins. Instead of using the built-in Build Order dialog in Visual Studio, take a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe.aspx) on the MSDN blog for a correct way of doing this (or you might end up with something that works locally but not on the build server).
The key MSBuild elements in the referred post are the following:

```
<ProjectReference Include="... foo.csproj"> 
    <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly> 
</ProjectReference>
```

Now, as for the packaging, deployment and consumption of those plug-ins:

- Each **plug-in project** should trigger package creation and publication in a **post-build step**. [This post](http://xavierdecoster.com/nuget-tfs-preview-a-challenging-combination) on my blog contains ZIP-download with quite lot of MSBuild stuff you can use to get started. E.g. I version, package and publish the NuGet package for a class library in Release builds. I'm using the NuGet command line tool to `pack` ([command reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command)) and `push` ([command reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Push_Command)) the package.
- The **consuming application project**(s) should run `NuGet.exe update <packages.config>` ([command reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Update_Command)) in a **pre-build step**.

Also pay attention you're **NOT** running [builds in parallel](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx).

Comment: You answer is fantastic...just one more detail.  Can you explain why I can't used `nuget install` as discussed in either of these two questions here http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/430477#post990450 or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462349/managing-nuget-package-install-folders

Comment: Currently, the nuget.exe install command does not have the same behavior as a Visual Studio Install-Package command. It's rather a "restore" command, ensuring all package contents are where they're supposed to be (but not running any PowerShell scripts the package might have).

Comment: I've updated the links I gave you, to contain a book reference which enforces what you've said.  Well done, though I am disappointed that nuget.exe does not have a switch that mimicks the full capability.  Certainly I can customize nuget.exe should I need to.